# How to use Regex to compare if the input is in the right format

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to compare if the user's input, such as "2020-03-24 13:20:30", has the same format of " YYYYD-MM-DD H:M:S".

```
@visualizer.callback([Output("start_time", "valid"), Output("start_time", "invalid")],[Input("start_time", "value")],) def check_validity(text):
    pattern = re.compile("**code goes here**")
    if (**code goes here**):
        is_text = text.endswith(template_date)
        return is_text, not is_text
    return False, False
```

Comment: if you are using a date then you could just try and convert to to a datetime with the format. If it throws an erorr then its invalid.

Comment: regex is not the right tool for the job. Another answer shows how it can be done but it would pass if you entered a data of 9999-88-77 66:77:88 which is probably not what you had intended. Check out localdate.parse() for a potentially better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking only that the string matches exactly the datetime-format you wrote and not whether the date actually exists, this regex solves your problem:

```py
>>> import re
>>> simple_datetime_re = re.compile(r"^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d$")
>>> bool(simple_datetime_re.match("2020-03-24 13:20:30"))
True
>>> bool(simple_datetime_re.match("2020-03-24 75:20:81"))  # Doesn't make sense from a practical perspective but is matched
True
>>> bool(simple_datetime_re.match("2020-03-24-13:20:30"))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation use less code

```
import re

# Create pattern
date_form = re.compile('^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$')

# Replace with the date string
return bool(date_form.search('date_format'))
```